# copy files and folders from cluster to desktop using PuTTY

Tags: putty, cluster

I would like to copy files and subfolders from a `cluster` that runs `pacman` to a `Windows` desktop computer using `PuTTY`.

1. First I would like to copy one specific file or subfolder as a test, for example `my_test_file.r` or `my_test_folder`, from the cluster to my desktop.
2. Then I would like to copy every file or subfolder that contains a specific word, for example `mykeyword`, from the cluster to my desktop.  Note that `mykeyword` can appear anywhere in the name of the file or in the name of the subfolder, not just at the beginning of the name.
3. Then I would like to copy every file containing `mykeyword` from my desktop to a specific folder on the cluster

I know this is a very basic question, but I cannot find the answer using `Google`.  Until now I have always used `FileZilla` to copy files and folders to and from the cluster.  Unfortunately after I installed the latest version of `FileZilla` I am having trouble connecting to the cluster with it.  I can still connect with `PuTTY` and want to copy files and folders that way if possible between the desktop and the cluster.

My question might be a duplicate of this question:

[Copying files using PuTTy (not PSCP or anything else, just PuTTy)](https://superuser.com/questions/367143/copying-files-using-putty-not-pscp-or-anything-else-just-putty)

However, that question has no answer and I do not understand the comment.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: This will explain the comment on the other question: http://winscp.net/eng/index.php and as far as I know, you can't transfer files using puTTY without an add in.   WinSCP is my choice.

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded WinSCP and was able to connect to the cluster and can see the files and folders I want to copy.  However, when I attempt to drag and drop them to the desktop or to `download` them they are only partially copied before I get a message about the host not communicating for 15 seconds and the copying process is aborted.  There is a recommendation to turn off the `Optimize connection buffer size` option, but no instructions on how to do that.  How can I turn off this option to see whether that improves downloading capacity?

Comment: Apparently I can increase the timeout interval to more than 15 seconds via the Connection Page (Advanced Site Settings dialog), but I cannot seem to locate the Connection Page.

Comment: Before logging in to the server, click the "Connection" tab and you can uncheck that, just beneath you can increase that 15 second timeout.  Those values are saved per saved connection.

Comment: Thank you.  I increased the timeout interval to 100 minutes then attempted to download a folder again.  Unfortunately the download process seems to have stopped after 22% of the folder contents were copied to the desktop.  I never experienced this problem with `FileZilla` and do not know how to proceed.

Comment: is the connection local or across the internet?  To me, your problem seems to be the connection since filezilla used to work and then didn't.  winSCP tries and fails eventually.  Also can you try from a second windows machine?

Comment: I have a wireless internet connection, the same one I used for `FileZilla`.  I will try using a different machine.  The cluster is approximately 4500 miles away.

Comment: I think those two things are next to look at: eliminate an issue with the windows machine and examine the connection between point A an point B, for the latter I would run traceroute in both directions SSH to the cluster and traceroute back to your internet ip and from a windows CMD shell tracert to the cluster).

Comment: I just downloaded `FileZilla` onto a different machine (a desktop, the first machine was really a laptop).  I had no problem connecting to the cluster with `FileZilla` on the desktop.  I suspect the problem was something to do with the firewall of the laptop, which has created problems in the past.  Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: In that case I doubt firewall, you wouldn't have made it to 22% before failure.  My first suspicion for the laptop is check for malware.